# Division by zero values in awk

Tags: math, awk, division

I am calculating an average score as follows:

```
average_score=$(awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.2f\",${sum_of_score}/${number_of_lines}}")
```

where sum_of_scores is calculated as follows for each greped ID:

```
sum_of_score=$(grep 271712:E1 M10.6.txt | awk '{s+=$5} END {print s}')

number_of_lines=$(grep 271712:E1 M10.6.txt | awk 'END{print FNR}')
```

However at times the value of sum_of_score and /or number_of_lines might be zero and hence I am getting an error:

```
awk: BEGIN {printf "%.2f",/0}
awk:                       ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {printf "%.2f",/0}
awk: cmd. line:1:                         ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

How can I handle this error?

Comment: You are WAY off base with that mush of shell and awk. You've completely missed the point of using awk and you're using shell inappropriately. Read at least the first couple of chapters of the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and you'll never write code like that again. See @TomFenech's script for calculating the average to see the right way to approach this problem.

Comment: Thanks Ed I will make sure I do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `sum_of_score` variable should be computed like this:

```
sum_of_score=$(awk '/271712:E1/ { sum += $5 } END { print sum + 0 }')
```

The `+ 0` means that `sum` is evaluated in a numeric context, so an empty `sum` is `0` rather than an empty string.

If you just want the average (the mean), then do this:

```
awk '/271712:E1/ { sum += $5; ++count } END { if (count) print sum / count }'
```

The `if (count)` prevents a division by `0` if `count` hasn't been incremented.

Your "division by zero" errors aren't really anything to do with dividing by zero; they're syntax errors. The messages in each error describes what's wrong!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful.